# Development Points in HARP

Tags: experience-points, high-adventure-role-playing

In ICE's HARP System:
After level-up I bought skills, stats etc and had one DP left over. Can I carry it over to the next level up? Alternatively, is there something that can be gained with one point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### DPs Must Be Spent When Earned

On page 17 of the rulebook:

> All Development Points must be spent when they are gained; any unspent
>   Development Points are lost. Many talents and options may be purchased
>   across multiple character levels, meaning a character may begin to pay
>   for a Talent at one level, and then meet the remaining cost on the
>   subsequent level or levels later on in their adventuring career.

So, you must spend your 1 leftover point at the time you gained your new level, *however* you can allot that point towards the next skill or talent you'll wish to buy at your next level up, which will make that purchase cost 1 DP less at that time.